# Is "(not A) or B" equivalent to "not(A and (not B))"?

Tags: logic

I'm trying to specify conditions in an UI with limited capabilities.

I would like to say "(not A) or B" but that's not possible.
Would "not(A and (not B))" be equivalent or is it equivalent to not(A or (not(B))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

not(A and not(B)) = (not(A)) or (not(not(B))) = not(A) or B